# Find committed version of an external patched file

Tags: git, format-patch

I've found a patched file in a old forum thread of a file for which I've a git repository.

I'd like to find out what version of the file was used (probably the one with less *diffstat*?)

I'm still a git newbie.

Is there already some git builtin for a check like this?
If not, how do I list each changed version of the file and checkout a particular version? (There's only the master branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the patch file (assuming it was generated using git format-patch), you will find a line like:

```
diff --git a/file.py b/file.py
index a344535..477ede1 100644
```

Here, `a344535`, `477ede1` are both commit id's (they are the shortened SHA/commit ids).

To checkout the file version from which the patch was generated, do a checkout on the commit

```
git checkout a344535
```

And now, you can do a `gitk` (might need to install with `apt-get`) on the repository to check further history.

Note: the `git checkout <SHA>` above will take you to a detached head state, so don't forget to do a `git checkout master` once you want to start working on your repo again.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. `git log --pretty=format:%h FILE.c | while read -r HASH ; do git checkout $HASH; WCL=$(diff FILE.c FILE-edited.c|wc -l); echo "$WCL $HASH"; done | sort`